# Plot the function by excluding one variable from from the first derivative of the function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

There is a function f(r,T) and df(r,T)/dr=0. From the equation T is not found explicitly. I want to plot the function f(r) using the df(r,T)/dr=0. How can it be plotted excluding T from the equation?

Comment: If your function has no other parameters, I would numerically solve the equation with respect to T and use this solution to build the plot. Of course, there may be several solutions. In general it is recommended to post your function. Then you may get a much better help.

Comment: Are you sure you said what you wanted?  In many cases, solving the zero derivative condition would leave you with a function of `T` (not a plottable set of solutions for `r` given arbitrary `T`).